# f:setPropertyActionListener is not working when c:foreach has a variable ID

Tags: jsf

Any idea why f:setPropertyActionListener is not working when I'm setting p:dataTable id="inv#{ck001.sequence}", which is a value obtained from the pageBean.

It works ok if I set it to p:dataTable id="inv1", a fixed value

```
<table class="layout-matrix">
            <tr>       
                <td class="layout-cell" rowspan="3" style="width: 33.33%;">
                    <p:poll interval="60" listener="#{ck001.refreshData}" update="@form"/>
                    <div id="availableInventory" style="overflow: scroll; height:1030px" >
                    <table class="outer-wrap"><tr><td class="outer-cell"><table class="inner-wrap"><tr><td class="inner-cell">
                        <p:fieldset legend="#{i18n.static.availableInventory}">
                        <c:forEach var="invBBD" items="#{ck001.distinctBBD}">
                            <p:panel styleClass="has-footer" >                        
                                <p:dataTable id="inv#{ck001.sequence}" var="inv" value="#{ck001.getAvailableInventoryViewModelList(invBBD)}" style="width:300px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{i18n.static.bestBeforeDate}: #{invBBD}" styleClass="strong"/>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <p:column headerText="#{i18n.static.productDescription}" width="200">
                                        <h:outputText value= "#{inv.productName}" style="display: block; background-color: #{inv.color}"/>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="#{i18n.static.birdGrade}">
                                        <h:outputText value= "#{inv.birdGrade}" style="display: block; background-color: #{inv.color}"/>
                                    </p:column>             

                                    <p:column headerText="#{i18n.static.supplierName}" width="200">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{inv.supplierName}" style="display: block; background-color: #{inv.color}"/>
                                    </p:column>             

                                    <p:column headerText="#{i18n.static.quantity}">    
                                        <h:outputText value="#{inv.sumOfQuantityOnHand}" style="display: block; background-color: #{inv.color}"/>
                                    </p:column>        

                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:commandButton id="chickenReplenishment" 
                                            update=":chickenReplenishmentPopupForm:chickenReplenishmentPnl" 
                                            process="@this"
                                            oncomplete="chickenReplenishmentPopup.show()" 
                                            icon="ui-icon-c34"
                                            title="#{i18n.static.chickenReplenishment}">
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inv}" target="#{ck001.selectedAvailableInventory}" />
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{invBBD}" target="#{ck001.selectedBestBeforeDate}" />
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inv.sumOfQuantityOnHand}" target="#{ck001.quantityRequested}" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>    
                            </p:panel>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </p:fieldset>
                    </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
                    </div>
                </td>   
....
```